# Twitter Bootstrap realtime progressbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

In a certain javascript function I am sending data across to a web service which in turn is saving it to a database.

I want to show that the AJAX operation is in progress. How could I show a real time progress bar and preferably with real time progress?

any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: I just have a variable that I set to true before the call is made. then when the call completes the variable is set to false, however I wanted to know if there was a way to do realtime monitoring?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no way to know much of the data in the HTTP request has been sent, a progress bar is not the best solution. You could however split a progress bar into different steps depending on the readystate. An example below for different values depending on readystate (can just as well be something else):

0% for readystate 0: Uninitialized 
10% for readystate 1: Ready
50% for readystate 2: Sent
80% for readystate 3: Receiving
100% for readystate 4: Loaded

When the readystate changes, change the css width attribute on the div inside the bootstrap progress bar, possibly also animating it with CSS3.